# Am I able to sync object types dynamically in TypeScript based on each other

Tags: typescript

I have Russian and English language dictionary and I want to sync them dynamically.

Let's say I have two objects:

```
const ru = {
'page.main.hello': 'Привет!'
}
```

```
const en = {
'page.main.hello': 'Hi!'
}
```

If I add key to "ru" object then I need that TypeScript makes me change "en" object and add there the same key.

```
const ru = {
'page.main.hello': 'Привет!'
}

const en = {
'page.main.hello': 'Hi!',
'page.main.bye': 'Bye!'
}
```

Needed result: This leads to typing errors because key 'page.main.bye' is not presented in "ru" dictionary.

I've tried to do something like `ru: keyof typeof en` and `en: keyof typeof ru` but because of self reference it doesn't work.

I do not want to choose one of the objects as base object because it won't solve the unsynced objects problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to do this is to just make a new interface specifying the keys you want. If you don't want one of the objects to be the "base" object, the interface will be the source of truth.

```
interface Language {
  'page.main.hello': string;
  'page.main.bye': string;
}

const ru: Language = {
  // Will raise type error because the 'page.main.bye' key is missing
  'page.main.hello': 'Привет!'
}

const en: Language = {
  'page.main.hello': 'Hi!',
  'page.main.bye': 'Bye!'
}
```

Comment: You can do better with template string types.

Comment: Yes, it is most easy to implement solution. No, i do not want to solve problem this way beacause it will made me write all keys in interface
I've tested solution with one object as base object and i think it can solve the problem.
Solution looks like:
const ru: Record<keyof typeof en, string>  = {....}
It'll lead to error when one of objects are changed

Answer (score 1):

The solution i've used is:

```
const ru: Record<keyof typeof en, string> = {
  'page.main.hello': 'Привет!'
}


const en = {
  'page.main.hello': 'Hi!',
  'page.main.bye': 'Bye!'
}
```

It provides enough flexibility despite my first thoughts. And this solution doesn't make me write dictionary keys in interface, i need to do it only in "en" object.